# Prevent recursion in Derivative of Piecewise condition

Tags: differentials

Can I prevent a RecusionLimit error when taking this derivative

`````
ut := a/Nt
Nt := Piecewise[{{At, ut >= At}, {1, ut < At}}, 0]
D[Nt, At]
````
`````

Comment: `Clear[Nt, ut];
Nt = a*ut;
Nt = Piecewise[{{At, ut >= At}, {1, ut < At}}, 0];
D[Nt, At]`

Comment: Thanks, I'll need to think about this. My post is a minimal reproducible example of the issue. I'm not sure if I can rearrange the actual expressions in the way you suggest.  Is this the only workaround available?